# Контроллеры в yii: когда создавать новые, а когда использовать основные?

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день! Изучаю yii, контроллер - объект, позволяющий по разным гет запросам запускать разные участки кода, если коротко, правильно ли я понимаю?

Основной вопрос, в какой ситуации создавать новый контроллер, а в какой использовать основной.

Как ими правильно пользоваться?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По разным запросам запускать, в соответствии с правилами, разные методы (`action`) контроллеров - задача **маршрутизатора** (`urlManager`).

**Контроллер** объединяет действия по какой-то вашей логике. Например, работа с пользователем (`list`, `details`, `create`, `save`..) можно вынести в контроллер `Users`. А можно отдельно разнести вывод информации (`list`, `details`) и модификацию (`create`, `save`).

Основной есть смысл использовать только для основных действий или действий, специфичных для сайта.

Всё полностью на ваше усмотрение - группируете так, чтобы потом легко было понять что где искать.